# CSS to conf/messages in play framework

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have messages under **conf** directory of play framework.

```
required.message=This field cannot be empty
```

And in the model, I have:

```
@Constraints.Required(message = "required.message")
public String name;
```

I am getting the messages properly on validation. What I want to do is, change the color of the messages. Currently I am getting as following:

[image]

I want the message "*This field cannot be empty*" to be in red color.

**Edited:**

View code

```
@(customerForm : Form[Customer])

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("css/bootstrap.min.css")">
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@main("Customer information") {
    <h2 style="margin-left: 5%">Customer Information</h2>
    @helper.form(action = routes.Customers.save()) {
        <fieldset style="margin-left: 5%">
            <legend>Adding new customer</legend>
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("Id"), '_label -> null,'placeholder->"Id")
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("name"), '_label -> null, 'placeholder->"Name", '_showConstraints -> false)
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("address"), '_label -> null, 'placeholder->"Address", '_showConstraints -> false)
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("city"), '_label -> null, 'placeholder->"City", '_showConstraints -> false)
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("state"), '_label -> null, 'placeholder->"State", '_showConstraints -> false)
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("postcode"), '_label -> null, 'placeholder->"Postcode", '_showConstraints -> false)
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("phone"), '_label -> null, 'placeholder->"Phone number", '_showConstraints -> false)
            @helper.inputText(customerForm.field("email"), '_label -> null, 'placeholder->"Email", '_showConstraints -> false)
        </fieldset>
        <input class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 5%"  type="submit" value="Save"/>
        <input class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 5%" onClick="window.location='@routes.Customers.list()';" type="button" value="Cancel"/>
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your view code with the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add desired style to your CSS style sheet and create a custom form helper that will feet your needs.

Here is a simplest example of a custom **customInputText.scala.html** file based on the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFormHelpers):

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div>
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div>
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your CSS file you can have something like this:

```
.errors {
  color: red;
}
```

Next you should add the newly created field constructor next to all imports in the view with the form so it can be used automatically. No changes are needed for the form itself. It'll pick the constructor implicitly:

```
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myFieldConstructorTemplate.f) }
```

By creating a custom field constructor you can reuse it across the whole application.

Comment: Have you tried it before? Are you sure this is what I need? Thank you for your answer

Comment: I've done it successfully in a few projects and if you use form helpers it's by far the best way to decrease code duplication. I see you're using Bootstrap so you might be interested in creating this inputs based on its API.